# Which is the different between the searchbar and the textfield?

Tags: angular, nativescript

Which is the different between the searchbar and the textfield?

How can I remove the search icon from a searchbar?

Comment: please add relevant code .. with so much of information nothing can be achieved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as in native iOS and Android these are two completely different controls providing different functionality.
Behind the NativeScript's [SearchBar](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/modules/_ui_search_bar_.html) stands

**android.support.v7.widget.SearchView** (for Android)

**UISearchBar** (for iOS)

Both native controls are pretty similar as functionality - as used for search bar (just like you would search in Google for example) they have specific functionalities like **clear** and **submit** events.

The [TextField](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_text_field_.textfield.html#hint) on the other hand is a control used for user input and has its own specific properties like **secure** which can be used when you want the user to input secure data (like password in form of ****)

If you want your user to input text you can use **TextField** or **TextView** to provide the ability for editable text input.